# Add Module code of BeforeDoubleClick_event to dynamically created worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have this code:

```
For a = 1 To 5
    strFoglio = "SheetName" & a
    Sheets.Add

    ActiveSheet.Name = strFoglio

    ActiveSheet.Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Next a
```

Is there a way to write code on these brand new sheets for example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Dim myRange As Range
End sub
```

Naturally, I'd like to do directly in the `For...Next` loop and not manually.

Comment: Check out the `Workbook` event called `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick` - if you code this it will prevent you needing to try and write individual event handlers for each sheet you dynamically add to your workbook.

Comment: @Sergio Obici check my answer below and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will run your `For` loop, create 5 sheets, and per sheet will call a `Sub CodeCopy` which will copy the code lines from a Module (in this example the code in "Sheet1") into the new created sheet.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateSheets()

Dim a As Long

For a = 1 To 5
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "SheetName" & a
    ActiveSheet.Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Call CodeCopy(ActiveSheet.Name)
Next a

End Sub

' **********

Sub CodeCopy(DestShtStr As String)    

' Macro to copy the macro module from sheet1 to a new Sheet 
' Name of new sheet is passed to the Sub as a String
' Must install "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility library" 
' from Tools > References.

Dim i           As Integer
Dim SrcCmod     As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim DstCmod     As VBIDE.CodeModule

' set source code module to code inside "Sheet1"
Set SrcCmod = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").CodeName).CodeModule
Set DstCmod = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(DestShtStr).CodeName).CodeModule

' copies all code line inside "Sheet1"
' can be modified to a constant number of code lines
For i = 1 To SrcCmod.CountOfLines
   DstCmod.InsertLines i, SrcCmod.Lines(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Code in "**Sheet1**" that will be copied to all new created sheets is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim myRange As Range

End Sub
```

---

**Instructions**

In order for this code to work, you need to allow the following 2 things:

1. Go to ***Tools*** >> ***References***, and add a reference to "**Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility**" library (screen-shot below)

[image]

2. In Excel Main menu, go to ***Developer*** Menu, then select ***Macro Security***, the click **V** to allow "**Trust access to the VBA project object model**" (screen-shot below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you want to create code directly on the new sheets created with your initial code.

So i would do like this :

```
Code(1) = Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Code(2) = Dim myRange As Range
Code(3) = '....

For i = 1 To 3
Wb.VBProject.VBComponents("SheetName & a").CodeModule.InsertLines i, Code(i)
Next i
```

(Just put it in loop)

Comment: If you want to give this answer you should at least quote the values in your  `Code` array e.g. `Code(1) = "Dim foo As String"`. Otherwise, your example code does not compile and someone, somewhere, should vote your answer down...

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it returns a runtime error 1004. I could fix it modifying my settings but this file should run on several pcs and I cannot ask to manage settings to everyone. I'll return to the old idea to copy a hidden sheet on which the code is already written.

Comment: Tahnk you for the advice Robin. Your idea is good Sergio, I think it is safer.